# ORA-01008: not all variables bound (in table adapter with parameterized query)

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, parameters, datatable, tableadapter

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2010 (.NET FrameWork 4)
- ASP.NET web Application
- Oracle Database
- using System.Data.OracleClient

  I have a web form where a user can enter any or no data into text boxes corresponding to each parameter in my query.if user entered no data the text box will get "0" value.

here is my query:

```
SELECT "CardNo" , "Name"
FROM CSC.CommercialCardList
WHERE("CardNo"=:CardNo or :CardNo=0) and ("Name"=:Name or :Name=0)
```

when I right click on the query from the  tableadaptor in the MYDATABASE.xsd panel, and select 'Preview Data' and fill parameter values with "0" i get the error (" ORA-01008 : Not all variables bound" )

can anyone help me?

--EDIT--

```
CardNo = (CardNoTextBox.Text != String.Empty) ? CardNoTextBox.Text : "0";
Name = (NameTextBox.Text != String.Empty) ? NameTextBox.Text : "0";
CommercialCardList.Fill(dt, CardNo,Name);
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

Comment: Can you show your code?  Not the SQL, but your VB/C#?

Comment: CardNo = (CardNoTextBox.Text != String.Empty) ? CardNoTextBox.Text : "0";
                Name = (NameTextBox.Text != String.Empty) ? NameTextBox.Text : "0";                                                                                    
               
                CommercialCardList.Fill(dt, CardNo,Name);
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);

Comment: Can you also add the code where you actually talk to the Oracle server?  It should have an `OracleCommand` object...

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind 4 variables as part of your code.

2 for "CardNo"=:CardNo or :CardNo=0

2 for "Name"=:Name or :Name=0

Comment: i used                                                                                                 CardNo = (CardNoTextBox.Text != String.Empty) ? CardNoTextBox.Text : "0";                                                                                                           you mean another one for :CardNo??

Comment: That might be satisfying only "CardNo"=:CardNo not :CardNo=0

Comment: I don't think this is right.  If you have `:CardNo` declared twice in the SQL, it's still a single bind variable.  I think he only needs two bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set command BindByName As true :

1- In OracleCommand as the below

```
 OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
```

2- In Tableadaptor as the below and call the SetBindByName with ture value

```
namespace MyTableAdapters
{
    public partial class MyTabTableAdapter
    {
        public bool SetBindByName
        {
            set
            {
                this.Adapter.InsertCommand.BindByName = value;
                this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.BindByName = value;
                this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.BindByName = value;
                foreach (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand cmd in this.CommandCollection)
                {
                    cmd.BindByName = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```